# Arranging small niche as storage space

Tags: bedroom, storage

In our bedroom with have a low but quite deep (~180cm) niche under. The ceiling there is so low (max 140cm) that to search and take things out from there you need to kneel down. We keep there many  small and bigs things: boxes, bags, Christmas tree decorations, old posters, jackets, etc.

[image: dimensions]

How can we arrange it so that:

- finding the right thing is easy
- getting the thing requires little effort
- it's good for storing both small and big things?

Options we considered so far included hooks and trolleys with shelves and baskets. What other options do we have?

[image: trolley from IKEA]

Answer (score 3):

I'd consider mounting drawer slides right on the floor. You could then install simple flat shelves with pulls on the front, or actual drawers with low or high sides (the latter would fit the ceiling shape).